# My URLs loads but pagespeed or cloudflare do not recognize them

Tags: wordpress, url, cloudflare, permalinks, pagespeed

I am working on new online store, it is being developed in WordPress. I have set URL permalink and everything seems to be working fine, unfortunatelly, when I run a speed test on "google pagespeed" it says ***We couldn't load ...(URL)....verify URL is valid***. If I remove the https:// and try clicking on Analyze button several times, then it works, but this is not normal. Besides that, I have recently set up cloudflare to use CDN and improve the loading speed, and when I try running a speed test I get the message: ***myvtechnologies.com/ does not point to an HTML page. Check your URL is correct before you run another test.***

My domain: myvtechnologies.com, the page is under construction, but you can click on any product and see what I report.

I have already contacted GoDaddy to get support on this, but they say everything is OK from their side. I would like all links to work propperly.